# Laplace Transform of $e^{a t^2}$

Tags: laplace-transform

What is the Laplace transform of $e^{a t^2}$, for positive $a$?

In order  for Laplace transform to exist function must be locally integrable.

Since integral of any compact set $e^{a t^2}$ is finite it is locally integrable.
So, it must have a Laplace transform. How do I find one?

Comment: Are you sure that this has a Laplace transform? The function needs to be locally integrable with polynomial growth at most, I think.

Comment: For the Laplace transform to exist it must be of exponential type and this function is not.

Comment: @SimonS by exponential type you mean $e^t$, right? And $e^{t^2}$ would be double exponential?

Comment: @CameronWilliams now I am not sure. I know $e^t$ has a Laplace transform.

Comment: $f$ is of exponential type if $|f(t)| \leq Me^{bt}$ for some constants $M, b > 0$. This comes straight from the definition of the Laplace transform as otherwise the improper integral won't converge. You can see your function isn't of exponential type and indeed the integral of the Laplace transform doesn't converge. I've heard an MIT mathematics professor talking about this saying it's not too great a loss because he didn't know of any physical models with $e^{at^2}$ for positive $a$.

Comment: Is there extension of Laplace transform that handle this? You know like with Fourier transform, by using distributions?

Comment: Possibly, but someone else will have to chime in if there is.

Comment: Would an inverse Laplace transform exist for a function of this type?

Comment: @Amzoti, do you know what definition of the Laplace transform WA is using? It would seem not to be one they articulate here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaplaceTransform.html

Answer (score 0):

> The bilateral Laplace transform is well-defined in the sense of analytic functionals

For $\Re(a^2) > 0$ the Fourier transform of $e^{\pi a^2 t^2}$ is well-defined in the sense of analytic functionals acting on the functions of the form $T \ast e^{-\pi b^2 t^2}$ with $b^2 > \Re(a^2)$ and $T$ compactly supported.

We then have $$\mathcal{F}[e^{\pi a^2 t^2}]= (-a)^{-1} e^{\pi y^2/a^2}$$ 
In the sense that for $\phi(t) = T \ast e^{-\pi b^2t^2}$ $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathcal{F}[\phi](t) e^{\pi a^2 t^2}dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(y) (-a)^{-1} e^{\pi y^2/a^2}dy\tag{1}$$
Proof : both sides of $(1)$ are analytic in $a\in \Bbb{C},\Re(a^2)< b^2$ so extend it from $\Re(a^2)< 0$ to $\Re(a^2)< b^2$ by  analytic continuation.